# Cant get values of inputs asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, input, webforms

My problem i always get null from my inputs or default value. Some how if i set value at page_load like Form_txt_Ad.Value="ExampleValue"; i can get it. But i cant get any value from inputs.

```
protected void Save_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string exapmle = Form_txt_Ad.Value;
string example = Form_txt_Soyad.Value;4
}
```

```
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" translate translate-attr-placeholder=".PLACEHOLDER_NAME" placeholder="Ad" id="Form_txt_Ad" runat="server" />
                        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    </div>

<div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
            <button type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="Save_Button_Click" class="btn btn-success btn-raised btn-lg" title="Kaydet"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved icon-marginRight"></i>Kaydet</button>
        </div>
```

Thx for help.

Comment: Are your input inside of a `<form>`?

Comment: <div class="row" runat="server">
        <section class="col-md-12">
            <div class="FormAlani">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="Form-Kimlik-Panel golge-2" translate-namespace="Member_Tabs-ID_Contact" >   not exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all your control elements are placed inside `<form> ... </form>` tag.

Since you have placed `runat="server"` you should be able to get the value by either using any of them

```
Form_txt_Ad.Value
```

(OR)

```
Form_txt_Ad.Text
```

Else use `Request.Form["Form_txt_Ad"]`

Not sure though why not use a server side control using `<asp:TextBox ...` which will allow you to get the textbox value directly using the `Text` property

Comment: i didnt wrote this code my front end mate wrote it. also i tried with asp:TextBox its same result now i will try form

Answer (score 0):

Add the *name* attribute to your *input* and make sure it's inside a *form* element.

```
<form>
...
<input type="text" translate translate-attr-placeholder=".PLACEHOLDER_NAME" placeholder="Ad" id="Form_txt_Ad" name="Form_txt_Ad" runat="server" />
...
</form>
```